# Proof category of $k$-spaces is "almost" locally Cartesian closed

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory

From [this comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/225374/which-nice-subcategories-of-mathsftop-are-locally-cartesian-closed#comment556747_225374) on [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/225374/which-nice-subcategories-of-mathsftop-are-locally-cartesian-closed) about locally Cartesian closed subcategories of topological spaces I understand the following proposition holds.

**Proposition.** Let $\mathsf C$ be the category of $k$-spaces. If $A,B$ are compactly generated, then $f^\ast :\mathsf C_{/B}\to \mathsf C_{/A}$ admits a right adjoint.

The comment directs to [May-Sigurdsson](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/EXTHEORY/MaySig.pdf), but it's terse for me and I'm struggling to find and isolate the statement and its proof.

(Remark 7.1.5.4 in *Higher Topos Theory* also mentions something about this.)

Is the proposition above true as it's written? How to prove it? When does base change along $\mathrm{eval}_0:B^I\to B$ admit a right adjoint?